# PoE injector to power wifi IP camera

Tags: power-over-ethernet

Can I use a PoE injector to power an IP camera where routing an ethernet cable would be more convenient due to cable length, but use the IP camera's wifi as the physical layer for data...?

I would like to put the camera outside my garage but the power socket is too far away for the provided power cord so routing an ethernet would be safer for outside, the cable length is well under PoE max (5m I need at most) and I have wifi all over... It seems to make sense...

Comment: The camera will have to support this. That's the only answer. If it does, great. If it doesn't, it won't.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't be a problem - I networked a camera using 10/100 ethernet and used the spare pairs within the cable to put the 5v 2a needed to power the camera, using the original power supply.